# laravel 5.3 upload file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm using laravel 5.3, and i want to upload a file to a directory. i've been following laravel documentation for uploading file, like this code :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->attachment->store('attachment');
}
```

but it get an error

> Call to a member function store() on string

previously on laravel 5.2, i've been use this code for uploading file and it's work

```
if ($request->hasFile('attachment')) {
    $destination = 'upload/attachment';
    $file = $request->file('attachment');
    $file->move($destination, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}

$filelocation = $destination. "/" .$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

but in laravel 5.3 it's doesn't work, and i get an error

> Undefined variable: destination

can you help what wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $path = $request->attachment->store('attachment');
}
```

I don't think `$request->attachment` does what you are trying to do. Change that line to:

```
$request->file('attachment')->store('/your/destination/path')
```

---

```
if($request->hasFile('attachment')){
    $destination = 'upload/attachment';
    $file = $request->file('attachment');
    $file->move($destination, $file->getClientOriginalName());
}

$filelocation = $destination. "/" .$file->getClientOriginalName();
```

When `$request->hasFile('attachment')` is `false`, `$destination` will not get declared. So when it reaches the `$filelocation` line you get an undefined variable.

Comment: hi,
at first, i've been use $request->file('attachment')->store('storage/attachment'); but it get error Call to a member function store() on null

Comment: That means the file() method isn't returning anything. Check that you are uploading a file an it has the name "attachment".

Comment: i've been set my input name attachment

Comment: <input type="file" name="attachment">
is it true ?

Answer (score 1):

In Larave 5.3 you can use simple upload file like this:

```
$request->file('file')->storePublicly($folderSrc);
```

This save you file to storage/app/public/you-folder-src